# Como fazer a navegação de um site se uma única pagina?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, front-end

Eu quero fazer um daqueles sites de uma página, mas eu n consigo pensar em uma coisa: como eu posso fazer que quando eu clique em um botão ele desça a página até o conteúdo referente?

No menu tem que ter um botão Contato e quando eu clique nele ele desça até a `div#contato`.

Atualmente no site o menu tem 4 botões: Home, Jogos, Perfil, Contato.

Eu tenho como fazer isso só com HTML/CSS?

É muito difícil fazer isso com JS/JQuery?

Por que não tem como eu colocar tamanho 100% nessas divs principais para cada uma ocupar a tela inteira e como eu posso fazer para o tamanho delas ser responsivo/se ajustar ao conteúdo? Uma das formas que encontrei de atingir esse objetivo foi `divs.height($(window).height());`.

Comment: Dá uma olhada [nesta resposta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/51952/4337) sobre "âncora", pode ser que ajude.

Comment: possível duplicata de [Rolagem suave link ancora](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/51944/rolagem-suave-link-ancora)

Comment: Não tenho muita prática de HTML mas julgo que pode fazer assim: `<a href="#ID que atribui-o à div">Texto do link</a>`. Note o `#` antes do ID.

Comment: @dheku Até seria uma duplicata, se eu estivesse perguntando somente isso.

Comment: @AndreyHartung bela edição, campeão.

Comment: Eu adicionei só +1 dúvida que surgiu vendo a outra postagem..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basta adicionar uma [âncora](http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/1995-archive/Elements/A.html) em sua página. Onde você marca o menu com um código, e a `div` que o mesmo irá chamar. Um exemplo básico de seria:

```
<a href="#principal" >Home</a>

<div id="principal">
Seja muito bem vindo à página teste!
</div>
```

Porém, creio que você busca além disso, aqueles "efeitos" de rolagem, onde possui uma certa animação.
Uma forma de fazer isso, a mais fácil que conheço, é utilizando [JQuery](http://jquery.com/) para isso. Neste caso, seu site ficaria desta forma:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) { 
    $(".scroll").click(function(event){        
        event.preventDefault();
        $('html,body').animate({scrollTop:$(this.hash).offset().top}, 800);
   });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="tipologias scroll ">
                                <li>
                                    <a href="#white-felling" class="white-felling scroll">                                        
                                        <div class="orbit-caption">
                                            White Feeling
                                        </div>
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="#chocolate-sensation" class="chocolate-sensation scroll">
  
                                        <div class="orbit-caption">
                                            Chocolate Sensation
                                        </div>
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="#secret-vision" class="secret-vision scroll">
                                        <div class="orbit-caption">
                                            Secret Vision
                                        </div>
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="#passion-touch" class="passion-touch scroll">                                    
                                        <div class="orbit-caption">
                                            Passion Touch
                                        </div>
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>


<div id="conteudo">
<p id="chocolate-sensation">
    <B>    CHOCOLATE</B><BR><BR>
    Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur?"Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur?"
    
    
</p>

<p id="white-felling">
    <B>    WHITE FELLING</B><BR><BR>
    Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur?"Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur?"
</p>

<p id="secret-vision">
    <B>    SECRET VISION</B><BR><BR>
    Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur?"Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur?"Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur?"
</p>

<p id="passion-touch">
    <B>    PASSION TOUCH</B><BR><BR>
    
    Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur?"Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur?"Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur?"
</p>
    
</div>
```

Segue um [exemplo no Jsfiddle para quem opita por ele.](http://jsfiddle.net/randrade/n4r2ao8n/3/)

Creio que você também vai procurar por efeitos de animação das `div's`, onde aparecem de acordo com o `scroll` da página. Porém, para um exemplo completo assim, aconselho a [esta pesquisa no google.](https://www.google.com.br/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=templates%20html%20free)

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta! Mas você poderia me explicar essa parte do JS que eu não consigo entender como funciona? {scrollTop:$(this.hash).offset().top}

Comment: e eu não sabia que o href apontava desse jeito também, achei que só servia para links u.u

Comment: Neste caso, ele está pegando a classe scroll(dentro do href), e faz uma animação, ao clicar. no final o tempo de 800, é o tempo de demora da rolagem. Você pode alterar de acordo com sua necessidade.

Comment: o scrollTop pega o tamanho a posição do scroll em relação ao topo. Olhe um exemplo explicando melhor aqui: http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_css_scrolltop_get

Comment: uhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh q foda! Vlw <3